# .NET 5 API with Entity Framework One to Many Relationship Not Working

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, .net-5

A CoreMasterAccount has many CoreSubAccounts. The two have a MasterAccountId in common. The CoreSubAccount has it's own unique SubAccountId. API json response will show SubAccounts[] but the array is empty. I did some debug work and identified that it was not an issue with JSONNewtonsoft serialization. No CoreSubAccounts are being returned. At a loss on this one.

CoreMasterAccount Model

```
public partial class CoreMasterAccount
{
    public CoreMasterAccount()
    {
        CoreInvoices = new HashSet<CoreInvoice>();
        CoreSubAccounts = new HashSet<CoreSubAccount>();
        TxnManualTransactions = new HashSet<TxnManualTransaction>();
    }
    [Key]
    public long MasterAccountId { get; set; }
    public string ForeignKey { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CoreInvoice> CoreInvoices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CoreSubAccount> CoreSubAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TxnManualTransaction> TxnManualTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

CoreSubAccount Model

```
public partial class CoreSubAccount
{
    public CoreSubAccount()
    {
        CoreCircuits = new HashSet<CoreCircuit>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int SubAccountId { get; set; }
    public long MasterAccountId { get; set; }
    public string Btn { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    
    public virtual CoreMasterAccount MasterAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CoreCircuit> CoreCircuits { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CoreSubAccount>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.SubAccountId)
                .HasName("PK_SubAccounts");

            entity.ToTable("core_SubAccounts");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Btn, "IX_core_SubAccounts")
                .IsUnique();
            .
            .
            .
            entity.HasOne(d => d.MasterAccount)
                .WithMany(p => p.CoreSubAccounts)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MasterAccountId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_core_SubAccounts_core_MasterAccounts")
                .IsRequired();
        });
```

JSON Response

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://localhost:5001/odata/$metadata#CoreMasterAccounts(CoreSubAccounts())",
"value": [{
        "MasterAccountId": 1,
        "ForeignKey": "X5202",
        "CustomerName": "Nunya",
        "CoreSubAccounts": []
    }
]
```

}

EDIT:
CoreMasterAccount Controller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CoreMasterAccount>>> GetCoreMasterAccounts()
    {
        return await _context.CoreMasterAccounts.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you query your data with EF? If you didn't include CoreSubAccounts then it probably won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't include CoreSubAccounts when you were querying your master accounts. Without the actual code that you are using to query CoreMasterAccounts I can only ques that Include is the issue. Try to write your query for fetching CoreMasterAccounts in this manner:

```
return dbContext.CoreMasterAccounts
.Include(e => e.CoreSubAccounts)
.ToList();
```

Comment: I will update the post with the CoreMasterAccounts Controller info. Adding that did not take - I may have formatted incorrectly.

Comment: You didn't add Include in your controller? If you just do _context.CoreMasterAccounts.ToListAsync(); it will not include related entities.

Comment: Gotcha, I hadn't removed the "await" operator so your code did not work initially. I removed that and it is working now. So, this call is no longer synchronous. How would I modify that to be asynchronous?

Comment: Yeah, I now get: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. xclutel-api C:\repository\xclutel-api\xclutel-api\Controllers\CoreMasterAccountsController.cs 27 Active

Comment: Resolved with : return await dbContext.CoreMasterAccounts
.Include(e => e.CoreSubAccounts)
.ToListAsync();